# Why does loading modules in index.html make them available in child states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-module

So, I am loading a bunch of .js files in my index.html with code like this...

```
    <script src="Login/login.js"></script>
    <script src="Home/home.js"></script>
    <script src="Authentication/auth.js"></script>
```

When i am in login.js, i can simply inject the auth module and it works without having injected the auth module in app.js (in the parent module) and also not having the following code in login.html

```
    <script src="Authentication/auth.js"></script>
```

Can anyone please help me understand the Angular mechanism that makes this happen ? How are child states able to inject the modules that were loaded in index.html ?

Comment: paste your code source

Comment: A file based explanation doesn't make much sense without actual code context. Show what you are actually injecting within the app itself. All modules and thus all components are available throughout the app

Comment: Angular works as a SPA. When you go to login.html, you're actually still on index.html.

Answer (score 0):

- I guess this scripts were writen in head section move them to body.
- I guess  that in login.js you do not get the angular instance and you
  get object from global state use self execusion function when you create the module.

Good luck!